# Running a simple Spring batch job without using maven?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am new to Spring batch framework. Can we create a batch job and run that without using maven?
I have seen spring batch samples connecting spring batch with maven..
Can anyone give me a sample Spring batch project that can run without using maven dependencies? Or at least give an idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, run them in a container like tomcat see here for more information; [Spring-Batch-standalone-Server-architecture](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?71748-Spring-Batch-standalone-Server-architecture).